# Como escolher o banco de dados no login

Tags: php, mysql

estou desenvolvendo um site de gestão de empresas, e para cada empresa vou fazer um banco de dados separado para que não haja demora mas consultas e tbm que uma empresa não veja os dados de outra empresa, a pergunta é como faço essa seleção de qual banco conectar na hora do login? estou usando o Mysql, Xampp...

att

Alexandre

Comment: Está usando PDO ou alguma classe (função) específica em seu código?

Comment: PHP, Bootstrap, Jquery e nada mais.... conexão simples por enquanto. Mysql_connect()

Comment: Rapaz, é uma página unica de login para todas as empresas?

Comment: Sim, uma única página pra todas elas

Answer (score 0):

Se você está utilizando uma conexão simples utilizando as classes do php para o mysql, então utilize a função abaixo:

- **Função:** mysql_select_db();
- **Link:** http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-select-db.php

No entanto as funções do mysql foram descontinuadas, a recomendação é utilizar o "mysqli" do php, já que não irá utilizar o PDO. Com ela você já define o banco de dados que deseja usar na própria conexão: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysqli-connect.php

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Certo. Eu já utilizo o Mysqli_connect(), mas como selecionar o banco na hora da conexão, quando ele puxa os inputs (DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) como coloco o db_name dinâmico, já que por exemplo, se colocar na tela de login 3 inputs, CNPJ,usuário e senha, sendo o CNPJ o identificador de qual banco vou usar...

Comment: Isso, no momento do login, ao instanciar a conexão você diz qual o banco você quer e pronto :)

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido pessoal, criei um banco mestre que contém os dados da empresa e tbm, o nome do banco respectivo de cada uma, ao fazer o login chamo o nome do banco e adiciono no $_SESSION[], depois na variável de conexão mysqli_connect(), obrigado a todos.